# want to write data in File.

Tags: c, bluetooth

Here i want to make one file and write some data in this file with c program.

How can i write this data with new line character also. same as like this.
And in 3rd line i want to put one variable value instead if `"BD_ADDR"`

Can Any body Please Explain me the way how can i achieve this.

```
filename = "asound.conf"
```

file contents :

```
pcm.!bluetooth {
    type bluetooth
    device "BD_ADDR"
    }

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "bluetooth"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) and [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/), so correct usage will be:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("asound.conf","w");
char *yourVariable; // Assign whatever you need
if (pFile!=NULL){
    fprintf(pFile, "pcm.!bluetooth ...\n\tdevide \"%s\"", yourVariable);
    fclose (pFile);
} else {
    printf( "Error opening file\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanx. There is any thing have to handle regarding error in fprintf() ?. i kknow about fopen and fclose.

Comment: @user1089679 yeah, you're right I've forgot filePointer in file, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

With [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html), [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html), and [`fclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html).

Don't forget error validation!

Comment: But how can i do this. i know about fopen(), what about fprintf()??

Comment: I linked to the POSIX manual pages. They explain rather well how to use the functions, even with examples.